# Вопрос про использование регистров в языке ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер

При изучении assembler немного запутался. Что в себе может хранить регистр? Может ли он хранить ссылку на какой-нибудь участок памяти? В чем разница записи `mov di,dx` и записи `mov bl, [di]`, названия регистров взял произвольно.

Comment: *Что в себе может хранить регистр?* Значение, размер которого определяется размером регистра. *Может ли он хранить ссылку на какой-нибудь участок памяти?* Регистр хранит просто значение. Это уже твоё дело, как это значение интерпретировать - как непосредственное значение, смещение, адрес...

Comment: *В чем разница записи mov di,dx и записи mov bl, [di]* Первое - копирование из регистра в регистр. Второе - копирование из памяти в регистр. Впрочем, зависит от синтаксиса компилятора.

Comment: @Akina, вот на примере ТС мы наблюдаем в чистом виде вред оверлоадинга функций (одно и то же слово move меняет свой смысл в зависимости от контекста)

Comment: @avp А без него сколько бы разных MOVxxx было бы?

Comment: @Akina, 3 (mov, st (в память), ld (из памяти)), каждый с 4 суффиксами (.b, .h, .w, .l)

Comment: @avp Ну это вкусовщина, какой из вариантов лучше/хуже

Comment: @CrazyElf, с оценкой лучше/хуже трудно не согласиться (как известно -- что кошке хорошо, мышам смерть)

Comment: @Akina ,  т е по сути 8 битовый регистр хранит в себе просто набор нулей и единиц и в зависимости от того, как я буду его указывать в инструкциях, будет меняться и его смысл. То есть для mov di, dx скопирует все биты данного регистра, а mov bl, [bi] будет интерпретироваться компилятором как скопировать из памяти данные по адресу числа,биты которого находится в di ? Сколько в таком случае будет скопировано из памяти байтов, 1 ? Как скопировать больше ?

Comment: `mov bl, [di]` будет интерпретироваться как "скопировать 1 байт (определяется размером приёмника BL), находящийся по адресу DS:[DI] (значение регистра DI интерпретируется как адрес в сегменте DS), в регистр BL". *Как скопировать больше ?* Указать приёмник другого размера. Например, BX.

Comment: @Akina , понял, все стало ясно, просто сегменты ещё не проходили в вузе, поэтому есть недопонимания, благодарю сердечно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регистр хранит значения, числа, величины - как хотите их называйте. Это единички/нолики. Эти значения могут быть чем угодно. Просто величины, коды символов или адреса в памяти.
mov di, dx  - в регистр di попадает содержимое регистра dx
mov bl, [di] - в регистр bl попадает содержимое адреса, хранящегося в в регистре di
например:
mov esi,OFFSET buffer  ; в esi адрес buffer
mov al, [esi+4]        ; al <= содержимое адреса buffer+4
mov bl, al             ; bl <= al

Comment: Да, спасибо, картинка сложилась. А когда  мы прибавляем к содержимому адреса buffer 4, мы прибавляем 4 именно к одному байту? То есть если оставить просто квадратные скобки, будет именно указан байт в памяти с этим адресом, а так мы берём адрес этого байта и прибавляем ему 4, то есть получается байт на 4 позиции дальше, верно ?